# Cannot cast type numeric to boolean

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, ddl, alter-table

```
ALTER TABLE products ALTER COLUMN power_price DROP DEFAULT;
ALTER TABLE products ALTER COLUMN power_price TYPE bool USING (power_price::boolean);
ALTER TABLE products ALTER COLUMN power_price SET NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE products ALTER COLUMN power_price SET DEFAULT false;
```

Postgres gives me this error:

> Query failed: ERROR: cannot cast type numeric to boolean

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use:

```
ALTER TABLE products ALTER power_price TYPE bool USING (power_price::int::bool);
```

There is no direct cast defined between `numeric` and `boolean`. You can use `integer` as intermediate step. `text` would be another candidate since every type can be cast from / to `text`. Values have to be `1 / 0` for the `text` route, of course.

Better yet, do it all in a single command for better performance and shorter lock time:

```sql
ALTER TABLE products
  ALTER power_price DROP DEFAULT
, ALTER power_price TYPE bool USING (power_price::int::bool)
, ALTER power_price SET NOT NULL
, ALTER power_price SET DEFAULT false;
```

Details in the manual about [`ALTER TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html).

Comment: Note on "values have to be 1 / 0 of course."

Actually values can be any. 0 will be false and any other will be true.

Comment: select 12 :: INT :: BOOLEAN

Comment: @Mahou5: My quoted statement only applies to `text` as stepping stone. Consider: `SELECT 12::text::bool;` -> `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type boolean: "12"`. So one can pick whether to be strict in the cast ...

Comment: In that you're right. I was only pointing that out based on the use of 'INT' as middle ground.